# Symfony Url Path

Tags: symfony, url, path

I work with Symfony 2.8 and testing with the built-in php web server.

My Problem is, if I want to open my Webpage I have to use the url:

1. `localhost:8000/app_dev.php`

After I build in the translator, the URL must be:

2. `localhost:8000/app_dev.php/en`

And in my Ajax.js files the link to the ajax.php have also be like:

3. `/app_dev.php/<route>`

I don't want to write the complete path in the browser and in my files to link.

I like to get directly on my startpage with http://localhost:8000 without typing `/app_dev.php/en/login` etc...

Comment: Enable rewrite on your apache server and you can get your startpage with http://localhost:8000.

Comment: I searching for a way to this in the build in php web server not in the Apache

Comment: You have to rewrite, this is not possible in the PHP build in webserver.

Answer (score 0):

If you want this behavior just change `app.php` to use the dev environment. So you don't have to type `/app_dev.php` and use http://localhost:8000

```
//$kernel = new AppKernel('prod', false);
$kernel = new AppKernel('dev', true);
```

Comment: Okay Thx, I've decide to setup an Apache and configure the rewrite, maybe it's the best way because I have less problems when I change to the production server ...

Comment: Yes it's the standard way to go, if you work on multiple applications you would have to start / stop the internal server which wouldn't be practical.